# ActiveRecord query alias field name output in jBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I am new to ruby on rails development. This is my controller function query

```
def index
    @questions = Question.order('questions.created_at DESC').joins('left join favourites on questions.id=favourites.question_id and favourites.user_id='+current_user_id.to_s).includes(:user).select('CASE WHEN favourites.user_id='+current_user_id.to_s+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as favour').references(:favourite).page(params[:page]).per( (ENV['ILM_QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE'] || 15).to_i )
end
```

From this query i dont know  how to get the value for  "favour" column in select query.

This is my jbuilder file in views

/index.json.builder

```
json.number_of_items_per_page @questions.length
json.total_number_of_pages @questions.total_pages
json.user_favour @questions.favour
json.questions do
  json.array! @questions do |question|
    json.partial! 'api/v1/questions/question', question: question,include_comments: false
  end
end
```

/_question.json.builder

```
json.id question.id
json.content question.content
json.created_at question.created_at
json.image_url question.image.url
```

when i put @questions.favour in index.json.builder
 i got  this error

```
undefined method `favour' for #<Question::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000c39b5f0>
```

Please Advice me on this issue

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should run the query in the console, and see the attributes.

Comment: i am new for ruby development. i dont know how to run the query with model in console.

Comment: go to the terminal, open the project folder via terminal and run the command `bundle exec rails c`, then just copy paste this query. `@questions = Question.order('questions.created_at DESC').joins('left join favourites on questions.id=favourites.question_id and favourites.user_id='+1.to_s).includes(:user).select('CASE WHEN favourites.user_id='+current_user_id.to_s+' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as favour').references(:favourite).page(params[:page]).per( (ENV['ILM_QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE'] || 15).to_i )`

Assuming you have a user with id 1

Comment: Thanks coderhs. I execute that command with query. But i didn't get **favour** column from the result

Comment: Can you share the result.

Comment: this is the result for that query => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Question id: 84, user_id: 2, content: "tghbdfrtgh", image: nil, question_type_id: 1, created_at: "2016-05-10 15:23:32", updated_at: "2016-05-10 15:23:32", width: nil, height: nil, category_id: nil>, #<Question id: 83, user_id: 2, content: "ghbfghb", image: nil, question_type_id: 1, created_at: "2016-05-10 15:23:12", updated_at: "2016-05-10 15:23:12", width: nil, height: nil, category_id: nil>]>. **It only return question table columns**